# java -jar myapp.jar includes ojdbc6.jar but throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jar, classnotfoundexception

`java -jar myapp.jar` includes `ojdbc6.jar` but throws the following exception

```
ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

The closest post I've found that works for me displays this solution for an  individual class:

```
C:\Project\bin>java -classpath .;ojdbc6.jar MyApp
```

but I need to build a jar file to deploy.  Every time whichever way I build the jar that refers to, includes, has `classpath` for `ojdbc6.jar` ends out throwing the same error.  MyApp works fine in eclipse with `ojdbc6.jar` in the project's `Referenced Libraries` folder.

Comment: Is the Oracle jar file in the same folder of your MyApp.class file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven, I would suggest using the shade plugin to create an uber jar. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

This way you can be sure no required libraries / jar files are missing.

If you cannot / do not want to use Maven, please provide the entire stack trace you get to help debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-verbose:class` to the command line to had the JVM show what classes are being loaded. If you don't see `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` printed out, then the ojdbc6.jar is probably not found.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your comments!

This worked: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Tipped off by other posts about -C option not suitable for classpath within the jar for other jars, rather take out reference to ojdbc6.jar in create jar statement and use Class-Path in Manifest (no spaces between lines--those were added by Stack's editor):

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Main-Class: MyApp

Class-Path: ojdbc6.jar

Created-By: 1.7.0_71 (Oracle Corporation)

Now create jar statement looks like this:

jar cfm myjar.jar MANIFEST.MF MyApp.class  Other1.class  Other2.class Other3.class

Regards,
Chase